# To solve a pg_query error message in PHP

Tags: php

**My code handler.php**

```
 ... 
 // independent variables
 $dbHost = "localhost";
 $dbPort = 5432;
 $dbName = "masi";
 $dbUser = "masi";
 $dbPassword = "123456";

 $conn = "host=$dbHost port=$dbPort dbname=$dbName user=$dbUser password=$dbPassword";

$dbconn = pg_connect($conn);

$sql = "SELECT username, passhash_md5, email 
         FROM users$
         WHERE username='a'        // to get these data from lomake.php
         AND email='a' 
         AND passhash_md5='a'";
     
     $result = pg_query($conn, $sql);
     if(!$result) {
         echo "An error occurred - Masiii!\n";
         exit;
     }
?>
```

I put "username=a", "email=a" and password="a" to a form which processes the script handler.php in Firefox. I get

```
Warning: pg_query(): supplied argument is not a valid PostgreSQL link resource in /var/www/sivusto/handler.php on line 56
An error occurred - Masiii!
```

I am not sure where the bug is, since I use the same syntax as [some examples at PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php).

**How can you solve the bug?**

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I did not know that you need to have the connection through `pg_connect()` in `pg_query*(`.

Comment: Autsh: It says in the manual *The default connection is the last connection made by pg_connect() or pg_pconnect().*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection is stored in $dbconn, not $conn

This is where you got your connection.

```
$conn = "host=$dbHost port=$dbPort dbname=$dbName user=$dbUser password=$dbPassword";

$dbconn = pg_connect($conn);
```

This is where you queried

```
$result = pg_query($conn, $sql);
```

It should be

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
```

PG_Connect returns a link to the connection, which you stored in $dbconn. You are trying to use your connection string as a resource, which isn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo:

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
```

use $dbconn instead of $conn in this line.